# Communication between a Python parent and C child processes in Linux

Tags: python, c, linux, ipc

I am developing a Python application that needs to spawn a child process (written in C) from time to time, to feed it some binary data and to get a reply. The child process will only be spawned when needed and will only serve one request. What are my options here? Is it safe to use stdin/stdout?

Comment: Try the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: You can try with http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html too.

Comment: @Whoami -- isn't multiprocessing for multiple *Python* processes? The OP wrote that the child process is written in C.

Comment: Yup. thanks. I missed that one. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

# Example with output only
p = Popen(["echo", "This is a test"], stdout=PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out.rstrip()

# Example with input and output
p = Popen("./TestProgram", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate("This is the input\n")
print out.rstrip()
```

The program `TestProgram` reads one line from `stdin` and writes it to `stdout`.  I have added the `.rstrip()` to the output to remove trailing new line characters, for your binary data you probably will not want to do this.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could drop `shell=True` by doing `Popen(["echo", "This is a test"], ...)`. In general, separate commands and arguments into individual list elements, eg `["ls","-l","/"]`.